Twostate predicate cannot prove parameter is allocated
Inside of a loop after an array of booleans have been allocated, the invariant allocated(sieve) reports true however, attempting to assert the Preserved predicate on the sieve array after an assignment asserts the following error. Why does it report this error and how do I resolve it?
    twostate predicate Preserved(sieve: array<bool>, i: nat) 
        requires 2 <= i < sieve.Length
        reads sieve
    {
        i*i < sieve.Length && multiset(old(sieve[..i*i])) == multiset(sieve[..i*i])
    }


argument at index 0 for parameter 'sieve' could not be proved to be allocated in the two-state function's previous state -- if you add 'new' before the parameter declaration, like 'new sieve: array', arguments can refer to expressions possibly unallocated in the previous state


    twostate predicate Preserved(sieve: array<bool>, i: nat) 
        requires 2 <= i < sieve.Length
        requires old(allocated(sieve))
        reads sieve
    {
        i*i < sieve.Length && multiset(old(sieve[..i*i])) == multiset(sieve[..i*i])
    }

should work.

Apparently I needed to add a label S: before the changes to the heap and then invoke it as  Preserved@S(sieve,i)

Perhaps, you could take a look here. I think it is nearly complete but the frames and two state lemmas are becoming quite fiddly. If you have any suggestions or advice on the approach I would be happy to hear it.  Like why assert multiplesOfINotPrime(sieve, i); resolves the preconditions but the previous line doesn't. Frames are so opaque ! https://github.com/hath995/Dafny4.4/blob/main/examples/Sieve.dfy#L578
